# Remove all characters following a certain character in a column of a dataset

Tags: r, regex, bioinformatics

I have a data set like the following, and the first column contains the groupings. However, some are labelled slightly differently. I need to remove all characters following the punctuation used (bracket, semicolon, comma).

```
groups <- c("Group1", "Group1", "Group1;Group1", "Group1(subset)", "Group1,ex" )
```

I would like this to present all of these just as Group1 (so they would all appear the same as the first two) - so to remove all characters in the string following the punctuation. I then need to repeat this for 1000s of groups, all in that same column of my dataset).

I know gsub is an option, but I'm not clear on how to use it to remove all of a string following a number of different characters, or on how to use it on just one column of a very large dataset.

Comment: `gsub("[,;(].*$","",groups)`

Answer (score 0):

```
substr(groups,1,6)
```

> ```
> 'Group1''Group1''Group1''Group1''Group1'
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You mention this will be needed for 1000s of groups with potentially lots of different separator-characters after the number. Here's an option that should be able to extract the first instance of the name regardless of the group number or the separator that follows it:

`sub("^(Group\\d+).*", "\\1", groups)`

The main innovations being that it uses the `^` to anchor the match at the start of the string, and the `\\d+` to match any number of digits after the word "Group". The `"\\1"` instructs `sub` to use the first capture group (in this case the region surrounded by `()`) as the replacement. You could also do the same thing in the `stringr` package:

`stringr::str_extract(groups, "^Group\\d+")`

which I just prefer the syntax of, in extraction cases!